# Talend - Convert String to JSON string array

Tags: json, talend

I am using Talend Studio for data integration to process data.
The data are stored in xml file, then are converted to JSON file. One of columns (partners) is a String element delimited by ";" separator.

**example** : "partner1;partner2;partner3"

**expected result**  : ["partner1","partner2","partner3"]

Is there any Talend functon to do this? or can I use java functions ?

Comment: Could you please explain in detail, what exactly you have done so far and the issue you are facing currently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with Json data in Talend is quite complicated.
You can achieve what you want with Talend components, but workflow is not so simple.

[image]

1. tFileInputXML : extract data from your xml
2. tNormalize : normalize the column where you have multiple occurences (here I used ";" as a separator). Number of rows in the output is the number of element in your column (in your example : 3)
3. tMap : I mapped my column, and added a fixed field "loop" for the next component
   [image]
4. tWriteJsonField : here you have to use attributes and loops to get an array. see screenshot.
   [image]
   [image]

Your question is quite simple, but the resolution is not. If someone has a better way to do it, I am curious to see it.